# bash process stays 20% CPU usage after boot

Tags: macos

I migrated from a 2011 MBP to a 2012 MBP via Migration Assistent and Time Machine.

Now, when I boot the *bash* process goes to ~20% and stays there forever, with it *launchd* for root and my user. I also notice, that the trackpad really gets unusual responsive. If I force quit the *bash* process, it restarts and does nothing and the system gets back to normal.

What can I do?

I already checked the permissions.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ps aux | grep bash` or similar? Most probably `bash` is executing some shell script which eats a lot of performance. Has Spotlight completed the initial indexing already?

Answer (score 2):

Select that *bash* process in *Activity Monitor* and click *Inspect*, then switch to *Open Files and Ports* tab. This should give you some clue on how that process was started and what it is doing. Otherwise update your question with that info, someone surely will help you here